# Delete selected row from table in php

Tags: php

I am using the code (pasted below) to delete the record from the table when it's selected by the `checkbox`. It is working, but it is not deleting the record from the table, it is only showing the `echo` "Records deleted Successfully.".

Please have a look at my code and suggest me some changes.

```
<?php
echo "Hiiiiiiiiii";
include("conn.php");
$sql="select * from test ";

$res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
    <table width="578" border="1" align="center" id="menu">
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>phno</th>
 </tr>

<?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
?>

 <tr>

    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emailid'];?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row['phno'];?></td>
    <?php
    echo"<td><a href='update.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Update</a></td>";
    ?>
 <?php
  }
 ?>  
 <tr><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="delete"></td></tr></tr></table>

 <?php
// Check if delete button active, start this
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo "$count";

if(isset($_POST['delete']))
    {
         $delete_id = $_POST['checkbox'];
         $id = count($delete_id );
         if (count($id) > 0)
          {
             foreach ($delete_id as $id_d)
             {
                $sql = "DELETE FROM `test` WHERE id='$id_d'";
                $delete = mysql_query($sql);
            }
        }
        if($delete)
        {
            echo $id." Records deleted Successfully.";
        }
    }
>?
```

Comment: Give us the output of $_POST['checkbox']

Comment: I have already answered you for for the same first question.

Comment: @ Gautam3164:its only show Array

Comment: `print_r($_POST['checkbox'])` the array!

Comment: @Mihai Iorga: yes, i am new for php and previous code was difficult to me for to learn so i try this code  its eassy but not working pls explain me

Comment: WHy not use the ID value you pass as ID.. ? (other than people could easily hack it which is another discussion)

Comment: @gautam:if i select 2 checkbox it shows:Array ( [0] => [1] => ) 2 Records deleted Successfully.

Comment: Oh the array is null that means it not passing the id's,have you noticed it..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<? echo $rows['id']; ?>
```

there is no $rows here remove the s put

```
<? echo $row['id']; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your file. Now you will be able to see all errors.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Also, use `var_dump()` to check what is actually in your variables. When you run `var_dump($_POST);` you can clearly see what is actually in your post.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
    $delete = false;
    $ids = array();
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $val){
        $ids[] = (int) $val;
    }
    $ids = implode("','", $ids);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM `test` WHERE id IN ('".$ids."')";
    $delete = mysql_query($sql);
    $id = mysql_affected_rows();
    if($delete){
        echo $id." Records deleted Successfully.";
    }
}
```

also your check-boxes should have:

```
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the delete code before selecting the records, then only you can see the actual records available in the DB.

```
    <?php
    echo "Hiiiiiiiiii";
    include("conn.php");

    if(isset($_POST['delete']))
        {
             $delete_id = $_POST['checkbox'];
             $id = count($delete_id );
             if (count($id) > 0)
              {
                 foreach ($delete_id as $id_d)
                 {
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM `test` WHERE id='$id_d'";
                    $delete = mysql_query($sql);
                }
            }
            if($delete)
            {
                echo $id." Records deleted Successfully.";
            }
        }


    $sql="select * from test ";

    $res=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    ?>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
        <table width="578" border="1" align="center" id="menu">
        <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>phno</th>
     </tr>

<?php
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
 {
?>

 <tr>

    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['emailid'];?></td>

    <td><?php echo $row['phno'];?></td>
    <?php
    echo"<td><a href='update.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Update</a></td>";
    ?>
 <?php
  }
 ?> 
 <tr><td><input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" id="delete"></td></tr></tr></table>

 <?php
// Check if delete button active, start this
$count = mysql_num_rows($res);
echo "$count";
>?
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Typo in the code that outputs the id:

```
... value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
```

It should be

```
... value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

Note that your code is also vulnerable to [SQL-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attacks. You should check if the ids in the POST-request are really integers.

Comment: Also, check Jelmers answer how to avoid such issues. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12490215/390808

Answer (score 0):

You should name the checkboxes something like

```
name="checkbox[<?php echo $row['id'] ?>]"
```

And then when you're trying to delete

```
foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $id => $delete) {
    // delete id
}
```

Your way of selecting an id by count is rather awkward, you're also only deleting 1 row, which  is apparently non-existant because the count is not an id.
Also, the value of a checkbox is meant to be an indicator off the checkbox being ticked or not, it's not usually holding a value, the usual way is to make the name hold what the checkbox actually means.

Comment: tanks to all for explaining me.

Answer (score 0):

you should move this code below of `include("conn.php");` in your code

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $delete_id = $_POST['checkbox'];
    $id        = count($delete_id);
    if (count($id) > 0) {
        foreach ($delete_id as $id_d) {
            $sql    = "DELETE FROM `test` WHERE id='$id_d'";
            $delete = mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
    if ($delete) {
        echo $id . " Records deleted Successfully.";
    }
}
```

Comment: @afshim: Please make yourself comfortable with the formatting tools we have on this website. For example, I edited your answer to show that there is a formatting for muli-linie code fragments, too. I hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id'];?>"></td>
<td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
```

Need to change as below to work it perfectly:

```
<td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="**<?php** echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
```